# Properly say superscripts locations

Tags: calculus, terminology

In english:

- $\bigl(x+y^2\bigr)$ is ('x' plus 'y' squared)
- $(x+y)^2$ is ('x' plus 'y' squared)

   How can I make the difference in english between the two?

Comment: I try to add a pause, as in "$x$ plus...$y^2$" vs "$x$ plus $y$, squared." If there's ambiguity, I sometimes make the parentheses with my hands while speaking.

Comment: Some people say "the quantity $x+y$ *pause* squared" to flag to the listener that there is something appearing in parentheses. I won't say this is much more useful than other methods, though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To completely eliminate all confusion, many people will use "$x$ plus $y$-squared" for the first, and "$x$ plus $y$ *quantity* squared" for the second one.

Comment: Also, "eks plus why, the quantity, squared".

Comment: Yeah, actually I like that version better anyway.

Comment: We use a lot of "the whole" like : "eks plus y the whole squared"

Comment: I think "$x$ plus $y$-squared" is still ambiguous. I'd go for "$x$ plus quantity $y$-squared," or "$x$ plus the square of $y$." Or "$y$ squared plus $x$."